# How to Resolve MODULE_NOT_FOUND Exception while Debugging React-Native App?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Exception while debugging React-Native code [MODULE_NOT_FOUND]

Just created an app using `npx react-native init May` and got the default React-Native App.js.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

function Section({children, title}: SectionProps): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionTitle,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
          },
        ]}>
        {title}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.sectionDescription,
          {
            color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
          },
        ]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
        backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
      />
      <ScrollView
        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
        style={backgroundStyle}>
        <Header />
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
          }}>
          <Section title="Step One">
            Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
            screen and then come back to see your edits.
          </Section>
          <Section title="See Your Changes">
            <ReloadInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Debug">
            <DebugInstructions />
          </Section>
          <Section title="Learn More">
            Read the docs to discover what to do next:
          </Section>
          <LearnMoreLinks />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

If I try to start it using `npm run android` (I'm using Android Studio Emulator) I get a message in terminal like that:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\-\Desktop\�������\���������� RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\-\Desktop\РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚С‹\РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёРµ RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.16.0

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\-\Desktop\�������\���������� RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\-\Desktop\РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚С‹\РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёРµ RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.16.0

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

    at makeError (C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\-\Desktop\проекты\приложение RN\May\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Android Studio's emulator starts working, gets to the Home screen, but nothing shows on the screen as I get an exception. Just started looking into React-Native, so I'll appreciate any help. For more information: I use Node.JS v18.16.0, Java JDK 11, code in Visual Studio Code. Tried using `npm install`, didn't help. Tried to reinstall Node.js, also didn't help.

Comment: How about you fix those directory names?

Comment: Those directory names looks bugged because they aren't in English, so terminal writes them like that. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Move it to desktop and try again, also open your terminal and type `node` see what you get

Comment: Yeah, it worked. So non-English folder names break code? Also how can I mark you comment as an answer?

Comment: You cannot mark comments as a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to Desktop and try again, looking at the logs the folder path seems inconsistent so use English directory names.